# useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component. MODULE FEDERATION APP

Tags: reactjs, webpack-module-federation

I am builiding a react module federation app.

This is App.jsx file

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { SnackbarProvider } from "notistack";

import routes from "./routes";
import { createBrowserRouter, BrowserRouter as Router, RouterProvider, useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';

const router = createBrowserRouter(routes)

function App() {
    return (
        <RouterProvider router={createBrowserRouter(routes)}>
        </RouterProvider>
    );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <SnackbarProvider
            preventDuplicate
            anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: "top",
                horizontal: "center",
            }}
            maxSnack={3}
        >
            <App />
        </SnackbarProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();

export default App;
```

This is my routes.js file

```
import UnAuthorizedLayout from "./layout/UnAuthorized";
import Authentication from "./components/forms/Authentication";
import HomePageLayout from "./layout/HomePageLayout";

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        element: <UnAuthorizedLayout />,
        children: [
            {
                path: '/',
                element: <Authentication />
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        element: <LoggedInLayout />,
        children: [
            {
                path: '/dashboard',
                element: <HomePageLayout />
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '*',
        element: <>
            <h1>404</h1>
        </>
    }
];

export default routes;
```

This is my HomeComponent/index.js file

```
import { Paper } from '@mui/material';
import * as React from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';

const HomePageComponent = () => {
    const theme = useTheme();
    ...
    const navigate = useNavigate(); 
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        ...

        if (!userDetails) {
            navigate("/", { replace: true });
        }

        ...

    return (
        <Paper style={{
            padding: '1rem',
            margin: '1rem',
        }} elevation={1}>
            ...
        </Paper>
    )
}

export default HomePageComponent;
```

I am getting error in HomeComponent/index.js file that

```
useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
```

Also I am using module federation app, is there anything to do with that.

I was expecting that useNavigate() would be accessible in the HomePageComponent as this file is in main host app only and I have already used BrowseRouter in App.jsx

Comment: Can you share the module federation config?